# Use HDRI without lighting the scene?

Tags: rendering, light, lighting, hdri

How do I use a world HDRI without lighting the scene? I only want it to appear in reflections (and maybe the background - not sure yet), but I want to manually light the scene with light objects. This applies to both Cycles and Eevee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer works for the **Cycles**-Render-Engine: 
In the **Properties Editor** select the **World** tab.  There you find the menue **Ray Visibility** (only in **Cycles**!). Uncheck all the boxes except **Camera**. If you want to see the world-environment in the reflections check the **Glossy**-Ray.
[image: Here the cube is not lit by the environment, because I have unchecked the Ray-Visibility for diffuse.]

[image: Here the cube gets light from the environment. Ray Visibility is set to the default setting.]

Answer (score 7):

A solution that **works in both Cycles and Eevee**:

[image: Node setup]

- Use a **Mix** node that plugs into your **Background** and **World Output** nodes.
- Use a **Light Path** node's *Is Camera Ray* output for the **Mix** node's *Fac* input.
- Use an **RGB** node's *Color* output for the **Mix** node's *Color1* input.
- Use the original environment input (like a texture) for the **Mix** node's *Color2* input.

Set the **RGB** node's colors as intended for your scene's ambient lighting as needed.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. Even lets you control the quantity of brightness without affecting other things in your scene. This is the complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

I usually surround all the scene with a big sphere like this:

[image]

then apply the map to the sphere and regulate the intensity of the background with strength parameter to make it coherent with desired lights this way:

[image: background sphere shading nodes]

And since there is no need to keep HDR informations, I convert image to simple jpg because is a lot smaller.
Result is like this:

[image]

Hope it helps!