# How to set world's background without effecting the lighting?

Tags: light, world

Is there any way to make the world's background white without making everything way too bright?

I simply want to make the whole world white, without effecting the lighting.

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49337/how-to-use-multiple-hdris/49403#49403 , https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108867/how-to-make-colored-backgrounds-not-influence-the-color-of-an-object, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34532/problem-with-transparency-when-using-two-world-images/34535#34535

Comment: for Cycles - World Properties > Ray Visibility > Camera (is the only one checked) https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/171096/2214

Comment: ThanksX ! How about eeveeee :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272

Answer (score 5):

Light path node (works for Eevee & Cycles)...[image]

Comment: How light path node works? :

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/light_path.html